# Problem with ad-hoc distribution in iPhone

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I am having a problem with ad-hoc distribution in iPhone. I have developed an application in sdk 3.2. I have developer's license (which was expired Today).  but my provisoning profile is valid. I made a build before my developer's licesee expired.

But when I try to install the app on my iPhone, i got an error 
"Could not install application on device. Error: A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted."

Please Help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this thread? http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21988-xcode-issue-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-deleted.html.

It has many solutions that could be yours.